# Shifting an arrowhead in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am drawing a line which needs to have arrowheads. I have the end coordinates, but because there is a little sphere there, it should be shifted just a tiny bit. Any idea on how to do this without manually calculating new coordinates (which would really be a pain). Perhaps changing the arrowhead definition?

[image]

```
#the arrow with heads that need to be shifted
set style arrow 5 heads filled size screen 0.03,15,45 ls 10
set arrow from 0.0, -1.0, -2.1908902300206643 to 0., 1., 0. ls 10 as 5

#the line itself:
set arrow from 0.0, -1.0, -2.1908902300206643 to 0., 1., 0. nohead ls 3
```

Comment: For what I understand, I would rescale the coordinates. For example, define `epsilon=0.9`, and multiply this parameter with the coordinates of the arrowheads, e.g. `set arrow from 0.0, -1.0*epsilon, -2.1908902300206643*epsilon to 0., 1.*epsilon, 0. ls 10 as 5`

Comment: This gave me a slightly shorter line, parallel to the original. It will do for my use, but still wondering about how to add a "top-margin" to an arrow.

Comment: @vagoberto To really shorten the arrow, the calculations are a bit different: `eps=0.1; set arrow from 0.0, -1.0 + eps*2, -2.19089023*(1-eps) to 0., 1-2*eps, -2.19089023*eps ls 10 as 5`

Comment: Right, on the rush I didn't take into account possible translations of the original vector. Anyway, OP should manually calculate the new coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me calculate manually the new coordinates :)

Suppose the end-points, in 2D, of the arrow are given by `a=(ax,ay)` and `b=(bx,by)`. The coordinates `(rx,ry)` of any line containing the points `a` and `b` can be calculated from the formula

```
rx(t) = (1-t)*ax + t*bx
ry(t) = (1-t)*ay + t*by
```

where `t` is a real number. Notice that `r(0)=a` and `r(1)=b`, so the original arrow can be drawn as

```
set arrow from rx(0),ry(0) to rx(1),ry(1)
```

To shorten (or enlarge) this arrow, you can use the same instruction for a value of `t` different from 0 or 1. For example:

```
eps=0.1
set arrow from rx(eps),ry(eps) to rx(1-eps),ry(1-eps)   #shortened both sides
set arrow from rx(0),ry(0) to rx(1-eps),ry(1-eps)       #shortened just the end-point
set arrow from rx(0),ry(0) to rx(1+eps),ry(1+eps)       #enlarged just the end-point
```